# Create class for Json (C#)

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

How to create a class for json if the name of the child element is not static? In the example it is named "2785989080" or "866191093_188530139".

**UPD:** Well, simply put the question: how to make a C # class for this json response?

Here is an example json:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "rgInventory": {
    "1853236180": {
      "id": "1853236180",
      "classid": "866191093",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 6
    },
      "2785011973": {
      "id": "2785011973",
      "classid": "1104575269",
      "instanceid": "480085569",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 2
    }
  },
  "rgCurrency": [],
  "rgDescriptions": {
    "866191093_188530139": {
      "appid": "730",
      "classid": "866191093",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposbupIgthwczbYQJP6c--q5OHluT8Nqjunm5Q_tw_ieyVod322w3l_hdvNjugctOUegU7NAmBqwToku3ogcXu6ciam3UwuT5iuyio602etQ",
      "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposbupIgthwczbYQJP6c--q5OHluT8Nqjunm5Q_txOhujT8om7i1Hg_0I_YGDyIdKWJ1RtNw3R8lK7lL--1MPq757OzSEx73Vxt3iOnAv3309KxEWqOg",
      "icon_drag_url": "",
      "name": "Souvenir Galil AR | Hunting Blind",
      "market_hash_name": "Souvenir Galil AR | Hunting Blind (Battle-Scarred)",
      "market_name": "Souvenir Galil AR | Hunting Blind (Battle-Scarred)",
      "name_color": "FFD700",
      "background_color": "",
      "type": "Souvenir Consumer Grade Rifle",
      "tradable": 1,
      "marketable": 1,
      "commodity": 0,
      "market_tradable_restriction": "7",
      "descriptions": [
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "Exterior: Battle-Scarred"
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "This item commemorates ESL One Katowice 2015 CS:GO Championship.",
          "color": "ffd700"
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "It was dropped during the Semifinal match between Fnatic and Virtus.Pro.",
          "color": "ffd700"
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "A less expensive option among the terrorist-exclusive assault rifles, the Galil AR is a serviceable weapon in medium to long-range combat. It has been spray-painted freehand using mesh fabric as a stencil."
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "The Mirage Collection",
          "color": "9da1a9",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535",
            "is_itemset_name": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "<br><div id=\"sticker_info\" name=\"sticker_info\" title=\"Sticker Details\" style=\"border: 2px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 6px; width=100; margin:4px; padding:8px;\"><center><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/eslkatowice2015/esl_a_gold.511130e5cd35082f8a58fe9510013e8b094b6f5f.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/eslkatowice2015/fnatic_gold.c9e28989883f9def16bebaf62ab506ab473915fe.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/eslkatowice2015/virtuspro_gold.f4d7fb45cc724daaa48b8fb5dc139bebc03aefbe.png\"><br>Sticker: ESL One (Gold) | Katowice 2015, Fnatic (Gold) | Katowice 2015, Virtus.pro (Gold) | Katowice 2015</center></div>",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535"
          }
        }
      ],
      "owner_descriptions": "",
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Inspect in Game...",
          "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D4774453798104612769"
        }
      ],
      "market_actions": [
        {
          "name": "Inspect in Game...",
          "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D4774453798104612769"
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "internal_name": "CSGO_Type_Rifle",
          "name": "Rifle",
          "category": "Type",
          "category_name": "Type"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "weapon_galilar",
          "name": "Galil AR",
          "category": "Weapon",
          "category_name": "Weapon"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "set_mirage",
          "name": "The Mirage Collection",
          "category": "ItemSet",
          "category_name": "Collection"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "tournament",
          "name": "Souvenir",
          "category": "Quality",
          "color": "FFD700",
          "category_name": "Category"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Rarity_Common_Weapon",
          "name": "Consumer Grade",
          "category": "Rarity",
          "color": "b0c3d9",
          "category_name": "Quality"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "WearCategory4",
          "name": "Battle-Scarred",
          "category": "Exterior",
          "category_name": "Exterior"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Tournament6",
          "name": "2015 ESL One Katowice",
          "category": "Tournament",
          "category_name": "Tournament"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Team6",
          "name": "Fnatic",
          "category": "TournamentTeam",
          "category_name": "Team"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Team31",
          "name": "Virtus.Pro",
          "category": "TournamentTeam",
          "category_name": "Team"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "more": false,
  "more_start": false
}
```

Comment: how would you expect to get that name then if it's not static?

Comment: What do you mean? You shouldn't be creating classes at runtime, and if it's at compile-time, you can basically copy-paste (except that just numbers don't constitute a valid identifier, but that's another issue).